# Have the requirements for a "positive question record" changed?

Tags: support, badges, asking-days-badges

It seems confusing why I don't have a "positive question record" on Meta Stack Overflow. The [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397) from the FAQ gives this:

> `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions ≥ 0.5`

Let me simplify it and change the variable names:

`q/2 - qdv - qc - qd ≥ 0`

Now, let's count them:

- `q`, the total number of questions

  - 8, as counted on my profile page.
- `qdv`, the number of questions with negative score

  1. [This should have been Improve Edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336856)
  2. [Add badges for handling topic requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334943)
- `qc`, the number of closed questions

  1. [Why was I supposed to review this as "Looks OK"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335740)
- `qd`, the number of deleted questions

  - None (as far as I know)

This gives us:
`8/2 - 2 - 1 - 0 ≥ 0`
`4 - 2 - 1 ≥ 0`
`1 ≥ 0`

So, in theory, I *should* have a positive asking record. Have the requirements changed recently, am I interpreting the formula wrong, or is this just a bug?

Comment: You have one deleted question that is also negatively scored.

Comment: @animuson where?

Comment: Here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332521/leave-comments-on-suggested-edits

Comment: Wait… why doesn't that show up in my deleted questions?

Comment: You only see deleted questions which were posted in the past 60 days. That was posted almost 90 days ago.

Comment: I thought it was "deleted in the last 60 days". I see it was deleted as RemoveAbandonedQuestions.

Comment: No, the list looks at creation date. E.g. if your question is already over 60 days old before it gets deleted, you'd never see it in that list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by animuson ♦ in the comments, I have [a roomba'd question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332521) (sorry, 10K only) that was downvoted and early deleted, bringing my asking record down by 1.5, to -0.5, meaning no, the requirements haven't changed. I didn't know about it because it was over 60 days old meaning I couldn't see it in Deleted Recent Questions.

Comment: For this specific reason among others, I think that all deleted questions should be visible on the profile page, no matter their age. There are two [feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341025/show-me-my-own-deleted-questions-and-answers-on-my-profile-page) [requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341878/list-of-all-deleted-questions-not-only-recent-ones) for this on MSO, both highly upvoted, one [status-declined] and the other one closed as a duplicate of the one that was [status-declined]. I think these feature requests should be reconsidered.